# Passing textbox value from View to action without using Html.begin form and Submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a texbox. When user give some input in the textbox and click the actionlink below, the value of the textbox will get pass to the actionResult(FWMenu) in the controller. I can not use html.begin form and submit button in the view. And i can not even use [httppost] in my controller.
Is it possible in that way? If yes then please help me how.
I have not used any class in model.

Below is my Controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult FWMenu(string username)
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

This is my View.

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBox("txtUserName")
    @Html.ActionLink("Login", "FWMenu", new { username = @Html.TextBox("txtUserName") })
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can send it through AJAX, but as you are sending sensitive data like username, think before using GET method.

Comment: No its not. You would need to use javascript/jquery to update the url of the link (append the value of the textbox). But why can't you use a form and post the value?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, This is just a prototype. In my project i can not use form and submit button every time in every page. So trying to implement it this way, if it gets successful then it will be a huge help for me.

Comment: What make you think you cannot use a form and submit button?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, It is because, suppose i have ten buttons in a page. And on every button click i have to call an action. Then i have to make ten submit buttons. bUT I want to avoid that. Another thing suppose i am using an image as a button, then will it be possible to make that image as a submit button?

Comment: Of course you can make a image as a submit (you can use css to style anything) but what is the difference between creating 10 action links and 10 forms/submit buttons - creating the forms will probably be less code anyway when you take into account the script(s)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks for your valuable time and advice Stephen. Just do me one favour more,  i have mentioned my code above. Can you please help me that, i have given a breakpoint at the controller in the FWMenu method on the line return view. When from the view the actionlink will be clicked then the value which has been given in the textbox by a user that value will display on string username. How can i do that?

Comment: Are you happy with jquery code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes i am sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript/jquery to build the url and redirect. From your comments you mentioned you wanted to use a image rather than a button or link, and that you will have multiple items, so assuming you html is

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <img class="submit scr=....>
<div>

<script>
  var urlBase='@Url.Action("FWMenu");
  $('.submit').click(function() {
    var userName = $(this).prev('input').val();
    location.href = urlBase + '/' + userName;
  }
</script>
```

Side note: No real point using `@Html.TextBox("txtUserName")` and if you have multiple instance of this it would generate invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and in any case the name of the parameter is `username` so it would have needed to be @Html.TextBox("username")`